# Raspi 3 hcitool cannot scan my smartphone

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

As title, I want to use my raspi 3 to connect my smartphone and send data, but however it failed.

First, I use `bluetoothctl` and it can successfully scan my devices and build connection.

However, I fail when using `hcitool`. (I 've use `hcitool dev` to verify that it is truely hci0)

I type `sudo hcitool hci0 lescan` to scan my BLE devices (android smartphone) but my devices cannot be scanned. I've wonder to know  what is the problem in it .......

(My bluetooth version is 5.43)

Comment: what do you see if you type `hciconfig`? and are you using raspbian or other os?

Comment: 1. `hciconfig` shows it is running (`PSCAN, ISCAN`).
2. I use raspian (image version: 2018-4-18 -> latest one)